# Accessing entire string in Python using Negative indices

Tags: python, python-2.7

Here is a Python oddity that I discovered while teaching students.

If negative indexing should work right, then for a string m='string', I did the following steps.

```
>>> m='string'
>>> m[:-1]
'strin'
>>> m[:0]
''
>>> m[-1]
'g'
>>> m[0:]
'string'
>>> m[:-1]
'strin'
>>> m[:0]
''
>>>
```

I want to know how to access the entire string using the negative index?

Comment: You can't. Unless `m[-0:]` or `m[-len(m):]` counts.

Comment: But why? this is not what negative indices where made for.

Comment: `m[::-1]` is always a fun demo.  Ask the question, "why does a list have a `reverse()` method but a string does not?  What is the difference between this slice on a list and `reverse()`?

Comment: Are you trying to reverse the string with negative indices?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
>>> m='string'
>>> m[-len(m):]
'string'
```

Just as positive indices count forward from the beginning of a string, negative indices count back from the end.  Thus, we have to count back by `len(m)` to get back to the beginning of `m`.

Comment: `n = m[-len(m):]` Then do:  `n is m`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you don't actually mean an answer like suggested by anyone else. What you want to know is why `m[:-N]` returns all characters in *m* except for the last *N*, **unless N is zero**, because -0 is equal to 0, and `m[:0]` should, of course, return an empty string.

Unfortunately, this is an insurmountable quirk of the language.

As a cop-out, I'll offer this: `m[:None]`, or `m[:(None if N==0 else -N)]`.